# How can I replicate this 1986 vox/piano/synth stab?

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer, replication

https://soundcloud.com/shreddyrayvaughan/rip-stab/s-K6UHX

This song is from 1986. That choir-like stab, I'm having a real hard time getting that sound. I'm hearing vocal-like sound, an e-piano and maybe a rhodesy synth? I thought this would be a simple find on the Korg Wavestation which has all sorts of tubular, airy sounds but I really can't find anything similar.

There are other sounds in this song that are so close to synth presets, that I can't imagine this stab is something meticulously crafted... alas.

Comment: I'm not enough of a synth expert to answer exactly, but definitely a sampler, which in that time period means either Fairlight CMI or Emu Emulator.  There were no other choices.

Answer (score 1):

Can you program a stack of two patches on the Wavestation? If so, stack the two patches that sound close but not all the way there. That is likely what was originally done to create the sound.

Comment: Some others have suggested EMAX or Emulator II synth. Went through every patch and couldn't find anything with the same timbre (otherwise I would EQ/layer the rest of it).